# How Can I split a comma in new column in r

Tags: r, split

I have this data

```
CHOM POS REF ALT
1    121  A   AA,AT
2    254  GCGC  GCGCG,AGCG
3    214  C    T
```

I need to split the ALT column to be

```
CHOM POS REF       ALT        ALT1    ALT2 ...
1    121  A        AA         AT        0
2    254  GCGC    GCGCG      AGCG       0
3    214   C        T         0         0
```

I tried this but the error is

```
alt=x$ALT
strsplit(alt, ",")
```

Note:
There are many different ALT and REF, the max of coulmn according to the comma is 4.
if there is  acomma just put the value 0 or NA

Comment: No, some times I have in the alt colmun like this AAT,CG,AA

Comment: so i need to split every comma in a new column

Comment: fifty thousand, it is big

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### New Answer

I would write a function like the following to split the column:

```
splitFun <- function(inVec, sep = ",", newName = "ALT", fill = NA) {
  if (!is.character(inVec)) inVec <- as.character(inVec)
  X <- strsplit(inVec, sep, fixed = TRUE)
  cols <- vapply(X, length, 1L)
  M <- matrix(
    fill, nrow = length(inVec), ncol = max(cols),
    dimnames = list(NULL, make.unique(rep(newName, max(cols)), sep="")))
  M[cbind(rep(sequence(length(X)), cols), sequence(cols))] <- 
    unlist(X, use.names=FALSE)
  M
}
```

Usage is simple:

```
splitFun(mydf$ALT)  ## Modify default arguments accordingly
#      ALT     ALT1   ALT2
# [1,] "AA"    "AT"   NA  
# [2,] "GCGCG" "AGCG" NA  
# [3,] "GCGCG" "AT"   "AA"
cbind(mydf, splitFun(mydf$ALT))
#   CHOM POS  REF         ALT   ALT ALT1 ALT2
# 1    1 121    A       AA,AT    AA   AT <NA>
# 2    2 254 GCGC  GCGCG,AGCG GCGCG AGCG <NA>
# 3    1 123 GCGC GCGCG,AT,AA GCGCG   AT   AA
```

The timing should be pretty efficient. Here's a comparison with the "splitstackshape" approach (which would also handle unbalanced situations).

```
system.time(splitstackshape:::read.concat(
  bigDf$ALT, sep=",", col.prefix="ALT"))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   1.197   0.000   1.202 
system.time(splitFun(bigDf$ALT))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.069   0.000   0.068
```

---

For the above, the sample data used was:

```
mydf <- data.frame(CHOM = c(1, 2, 1), POS = c(121, 254, 123), 
                   REF = c("A", "GCGC", "GCGC"), 
                   ALT = c("AA,AT", "GCGCG,AGCG", "GCGCG,AT,AA"))
mydf
#   CHOM POS  REF         ALT
# 1    1 121    A       AA,AT
# 2    2 254 GCGC  GCGCG,AGCG
# 3    1 123 GCGC GCGCG,AT,AA

bigDf <- do.call(rbind, replicate(10000, mydf, simplify = FALSE))
```

#### Old Answer

You can try `concat.split` from my "splitstackshape" package:

```
library(splitstackshape)
concat.split(mydf, "ALT", ",")  ## Add `drop = TRUE` to drop the original column
#   CHOM POS  REF        ALT ALT_1 ALT_2
# 1    1 121    A      AA,AT    AA    AT
# 2    2 254 GCGC GCGCG,AGCG GCGCG  AGCG
```

There is also `colsplit` from the "reshape2" package:

```
library(reshape2)
colsplit(as.character(mydf$ALT), ",", c("ALT", "ALT1"))
#     ALT ALT1
# 1    AA   AT
# 2 GCGCG AGCG
```

You can use `cbind` to add the output to your original dataset.

Comment: I wasn't aware of `splitstackshape`, very nice function: `concat.split` +1 of course!

Comment: Could its speed be improved with `...,colClasses="character")`? That's part of standard advice for enhancing `read.table`'s efficiency.

Comment: @IShouldBuyABoat, you've been credited with the inspiration for this function ([see here](http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/splitstackshape/functions/concat.split.html)). If the resulting split would be balanced, I have [a variation of the function](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/6873058) that uses `fread` that is *much* faster. This function uses `fill = TRUE` for when the splits might be unbalanced and it uses `count.fields` to check whether any rows past the first 6 have more fields than the first few rows. `count.fields` could probably be replaced with `grep` for a bit more speed.

Comment: If there's any credit due, it should probably extend to @GaborGrothendieck. I'm pretty sure I learned that trick from one of his Rhelp postings.

Comment: there are some coulmn still have a comma, to be clear I need if there is a comma but it in a new column if there is not just put 0 or NA.

Answer (score 2):

Consider your data is `dat`

```
> dat2 <- data.frame(dat[, -4], sapply(strsplit(levels(dat$ALT), ","), cbind))
> colnames(dat2)[4:5] <- c("ALT", "ALT1")
> dat2
  CHOM POS  REF ALT  ALT1
1    1 121    A  AA GCGCG
2    2 254 GCGC  AT  AGCG
```

Comment: Only accidental success I think. Unless you use `levels(dat$ALT)[dat$ALT]` this will fail when some of the levels are repeated at irregular positions. Consider switching to use `as.character(dat$ALT)`

Comment: dat2 <- data.frame(x[, -4], sapply(strsplit(levels(x$ALT), ","), cbind))
Error in data.frame("A", c("A", "AAAAAG"), c("A", "AAAAAGAAAAG"), c("A",  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 2, 3

Answer (score 1):

```
> dat[ c("ALT", "ALT1")] <- read.table(text=as.character(dat$ALT), sep=",")
> dat
  CHOM POS  REF   ALT ALT1
1    1 121    A    AA   AT
2    2 254 GCGC GCGCG AGCG
```

Comment: +1. This is pretty much what inspired my `concat.split` function to begin with :-)

Comment: Yeah. It's probably a duplicate, but SO doesn't reward identifying or confirming dups, so I alternate between doing the searching and just posting answers. I just did a search and didn't find what I was looking for immediately, but there certainly are a lot of interesting variations on this question.

Comment: Maybe it will work, but can I split just when there is acomma. like this

Comment: AA,T,G row2 is A T . it will be AA T G then A T NA